# ActivityResultLauncher is null

Tags: java, android

Since `startActivityForResult()` is now deprecated, this is how I try to get the result of my intent:

```java
public class Stt extends MainActivity {
    private TextView _dialogText;

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        // do something with data
                    }
                }
            });


    public Stt(View targetView, Context context) {
        _dialogText = targetView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        ImageView dialogSst = targetView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_sst);

        dialogSst.setOnClickListener(_view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH); 
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something ...");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

            activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        });

    }
}
```

So there must be something wrong with `activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);` since I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
> android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
> reference

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You seem to be missing most of your activity. Where are you setting up your UI? If the answer is that somewhere you are calling `new Stt()` to create an instance of this class, that is not going to work. This code needs to use a real activity, one that is started with `startActivity()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare from MainActivity I am showing a dialog (a class that extends `DialogFragment`) and from this class, I am calling `new Stt()`. The reason why I created the class `Stt` is because I will use that intent in my dialog and also in MainActivity. So I don't want to write the same code twice.

Comment: "I will use that intent in my dialog" -- I do not know if that is practical. Regardless, your current approach will not work. Perhaps you could write `Stt` to take an `Activity` as a constructor parameter, and use that for all the things that you need an `Activity` for.